# Allowing only one download per Apple ID

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm creating an app that I want to license out to businesses on a per-device model. The more devices they want to use it on, the more licenses they are forced to purchase.

But if all the devices are signed into the same Apple ID, as most businesses do, the business can simply download the app once for a fee and then re-download it as many times as they want on all their other devices. Is there a way to limit the amount of downloads per Apple ID, or to register an app to a specific iPad so that it can not be downloaded and used again?

Comment: But what happen if the user syncs the app via iTunes ?

Comment: @MidhunMP OP has to put in a runtime check, and not download protection. But it's a bad idea anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple stopped supporting a unique identifier for iOS. [The source code given in Below link](https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5) solves the problem. It generates a unique identifier based on the mac address of the device in combination with the bundle identifier.
https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5

i am Agree with H2CO3's Answer

Doing this, however, is fundamentally against Apple's UX policy and most likely your app will be rejected.

As per their guidelines User should able to use the App in his all Device associated with his ID. In future if he Lost his device, Then  App should be capable to Synchronize the purchase data with That Device.

How Ever you can Create Login/Sign-up for your app And Store the Unique ID in your server And You can Restrict use of one device at a particular time.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't really do this. Apple's software philosophy is that once you downloaded it, you can use, delete, redownload it any times without additional fees.

One "solution" (rather a workaround) I can think of is registering some kind of device ID (such as the serial number, MAC addres, etc.) - that serves as a unique identifier - with your own server and restricting access to your app only when that particular device ID is found. Doing this, however, is fundamentally against Apple's UX policy and most likely your app will be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could make your app so that a user account is required and let them pay per user account. You can prevent a login on multiple devices by generating a unique random key on the device and testing that at login (on a web service).